# node.js giving Error: bind EINVAL

Tags: node.js

I am learning Node.js and i am doing some sample code on udp .I am trying to implement a udp server to listen to multicast message and my basic code is this

```
var server = require('dgram').createSocket('udp4');
server.on('message', function(message, rinfo) {
console.log('server got message: ' + message + ' from ' + rinfo.address +
':' + rinfo.port);
});
server.bind(4000);
server.addMembership('230.1.2.3');
```

but node gives me an error,

```
events.js:72     
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                     
        Error: bind EINVAL                      
at errnoException (dgram.js:440:11)     
at dgram.js:207:28                                   
at dns.js:72:18                                  
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)            
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)        
at startup (node.js:119:16)                          
at node.js:901:3
```

also i am using windows 7 .please help...

Comment: Which node version are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var server = require('dgram').createSocket('udp4');
server.on('message', function(message, rinfo) {
    console.log('server got message: ' + message + ' from ' + rinfo.address +
    ':' + rinfo.port);
});
server.bind(4000,function(){
    server.addMembership('230.1.2.3');
});
```

On second thought this error may arise due to several reasons like socket is busy, socket is closed, port is in use by some other process etc. so check for those too.

Found a reference after some googleing:https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4944

Comment: I've tried move addMembership to server.on("listening",function(){}) event,and it worked.

Comment: I got rid of the EINVAL error by running server.bind(port, '0.0.0.0') instead of server.bind(port, 'localhost').......